# Have I done enough to debrief our customers?

Tags: automated-testing, test-management

**Below is my situation:**

- employed by a QA contract firm
- have come to the end of my 8 week contract with current customers
- need to pass on developed automated test framework and test cases to customers

**Our customer's situation:**

- have no testers with programming background

**What I am trying to deliver to our customers by the end of my contract:**

- Framework UML diagrams, showing how modules are tied together
- Test case logic flow charts, showing how each test case is executed with details
- A selenium cheat sheet like this one: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/
- Page Object Model diagrams for each web page under test
- examples showing how to write a new test, e.g. which files need to be edited,
- examples showing how to diagnose a test failure, e.g. how to interpret common exceptions
- create sample test scenarios to train customers' testers, supervise them to finish sample scenarios.
- well documented / commented codes with detailed explanations.
- A list of outstanding issues and if not fixed, their consequences; my recommendations regarding how to fix them.

Is there anything else I should add to my list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems ok, but you should add also the setup for the framework.

- How to install the framework?
- What do you need to execute a test/suite (Java installed, Selenium, any driver if needed)?
- How to run smoke/regression (if you have a lot of tests)?
- Additionally you could add a small documentation and/or links to online official documentation for: the framework, page object model documentation, w3schools CSS and x-path selectors if needed.
- As a bonus you could add few personal tips and tricks like best practices, always to code review, always to check/run their code before submitting to any repository to avoid issues.